# Atomic read and delete from Redis using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, atomic

Is there an easy way to atomically read a value and then delete it from Redis using StackExchange c# driver?
I am buffering items in Redis and when they reach a certain threshold I retrieve them, but I also want to flush my buffer.
I need to mention that I store items in a list and by "flushing the buffer" I mean I want to delete the list.
"key" : [list of items]

Comment: Wrap it in a [transaction](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Transactions.md)?

Comment: http://www.rediscookbook.org/get_and_delete.html should work with StackExchange.Redis as well.

Comment: @apokryfos Exactly! Good point! Thanks!

Comment: @Christian.K I read that one, but I was wondering if there's an out of the box method or something in the API ( since it's been officially a few hours I am working with StackExchange driver and Redis for that matter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a transaction and do the GET/DEL atomically, like this:

```
var db = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
var tran = db.CreateTransaction();
var getResult = tran.StringGetAsync(key);
tran.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
tran.Execute();
var value = getResult.Result;
```

This will send the following commands to Redis:

> ```
> MULTI
> GET "key"
> DEL "key"
> EXEC
> ```

Comment: If your key is a list, you should probably change the call to `tran.ListRangeAsync`

Comment: That's exactly what I should do!

Comment: @thepirat000 , If multiple apps (or the same app on multiple servers) are making this request to Redis. Will this code make sure only one will succeed?